# Публикация npm пакета через прокси

Tags: ubuntu, npm

Не могу залить npm пакет на сервер. Пробовал такие варианты.
.npmrc

```
https-proxy=itproxy.ab.loc:3128
proxy=itproxy.ab.loc:3128
```

ответ

> npm ERR! publish Failed PUT undefined
>   npm ERR! Invalid protocol: itproxy.ab.loc

если ставлю схему

```
 https-proxy=http://itproxy.ab.loc:3128  
 proxy=http://itproxy.ab.loc:3128
```

или

```
https-proxy=https://itproxy.ab.loc:3128  
proxy=http://itproxy.ab.loc:3128
```

или вообще убираю прокси. 
Тогда получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: bash: `export http_proxy=`?

Comment: @donRumata То же самое. делаю export http_proxy=itproxy.ab.loc:3128 тогда Failed PUT undefined (Invalid protocol: itproxy.ab.loc). Если передаю схемы - возвращает ошибку, как на картинке

Comment: Ну а в логах прокси чё написано?

Comment: Оказывается без прокси нужно было отправлять. Хотя у меня и была инструкция `NO_PROXY=*.ab.loc`, но была без порта, вот так помогло `NO_PROXY=some_url.ab.loc:PORT`